# Dropdown Button is not working in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to insert a dropdown button but it just doesn't work on my page. I have inserted in my page everything that needs to be inserted from the bootstrap for it to work, but it still doesn't work. What's wrong with my code that it doesn't work?

```
<head>

   <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<title>Consult</title>
</head>


<body>

 <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10">
    
    Category:
    
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the required the bootstrap javascript.
Add the below before your closing body tag.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: But why isn't this code snippet in the Getting Started part of the Bootstrap page?

Comment: It is right there in the Getting Started, you probably overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

It is running you can see by running below snippet

```html
<head>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Consult</title>
</head>


<body>

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
      <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10">

        Category:

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
        </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

That's same code you used which is running

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, maybe a connection problem caused javascript file not loading.